# Error in saving XML File

Tags: c#, xml, file-handling

I have a piece of C# code which saves the track information currently played by Itunes into a XML File. The piece of code works fine some time but generally gives the error "the process cannot access the xml file because it is being used by another process c#" on myXmlDocument.Save(ClsUtils.XmlPath);

Can any one suggest what might be going wrong in here.....

Following is the piece of Code

```
public void ModifyLastTrack(bool bOnlyPlayerPosition)
    {

        //initilize XML Document
        XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

        //load Xml into document
        myXmlDocument.Load(ClsUtils.XmlPath);

        //get Node for modify if Checked state Changed
        XmlNode DictLastTrackNode;
        DictLastTrackNode = myXmlDocument.DocumentElement;

        foreach (XmlNode ChildDictNode1 in DictLastTrackNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode ChildDictNode2 in ChildDictNode1.ChildNodes)
            {

                if (!bOnlyPlayerPosition)
                {

                    if (ChildDictNode2.Name == "TrackID")
                        ChildDictNode2.InnerText = TrackID;
                                       }
                else
                {
                    if (ChildDictNode2.Name == "PlayerPosition")
                        ChildDictNode2.InnerText = PlayerPosition.ToString();
                }
            }

        }


        //save Xml after modification
        myXmlDocument.Save(ClsUtils.XmlPath);

    }
```

Comment: Apparently another process is keeping the file open....

Comment: This error usually occurs when you have not `Disposed` of the original XMLDocument, where in your code are you `Disposing` of the `myXmlDocument` after you save the contents..? try Disposing it or wraping the creation of the XmlDocument object in a `using(){}`
after `myXmlDocument.Save(ClsUtils.XmlPath)` add the following `((IDisposable)myXmlDocument).Dispose();`

Comment: @DJKRAZE - total bollocks,. XmlDocuemnt is not eeven IDispsable. Besides it's clear that `Save()` and `Load()` don't leave anything unclosed.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the process which is causing this issue by the following code, but I'm not suggesting that's the best idea:

```
 string fileName = @"D:\pathname.jpg";//Path to locked file

Process Handletool = new Process();
Handletool.StartInfo.FileName = "handle.exe";
Handletool.StartInfo.Arguments = fileName+" /accepteula";
Handletool.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Handletool.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Handletool.Start();           
Handletool.WaitForExit();
string outputTool = Handletool.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

string matchPattern = @"(?<=\s+pid:\s+)\b(\d+)\b(?=\s+)";
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(outputTool, matchPattern))
{
    Process.GetProcessById(int.Parse(match.Value)).Kill();
}
```

You can get Handle.exe from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx)

Understand that the problem is that someone opened the file, probably you or a program written by you. make sure you close each time you open a stream or use `using` statement.
another way, that might be better, will be to add number to the xml you are trying to save in the case of another process occupying the file

Comment: The OP is monitoring iTunes. Your solution might very well kill iTunes. Or another essential process.

Comment: @HenkHolterman i know, that's why i said it's not suggested... but it's a solution, as well as what i wrote down